# Angular 4 Using Guard for Conditional Display

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the following CanActivate that I use in my HomeComponent:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      // logged in so return true
      return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
  }
}
```

So in my app.routing:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

This is the service that I use to login:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        console.log('logging in user');
        console.log(username);
        return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                const user = response.json();
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }

                return user;
            });
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
```

My layout is structured like:

```
<app-layout-header></app-layout-header>

<app-alert></app-alert>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-layout-footer></app-layout-footer>
```

Where the header is like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">plant-simulator</a>

    <!-- Show this for logged out users -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
          routerLink="/register"
          routerLinkActive="active">
          Sign Up
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Show this for logged in users -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
          [routerLink]="['/profile', currentUser.firstName]"
          routerLinkActive="active">
          {{ currentUser.email }}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
           [routerLink]="['/login']">
           Logout
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In this header html, I would like to make use of the AuthGuard and display the logged in user if he has logged in, else I would like to show the SignUp link!

Any ideas?

EDIT: After suggestion from the post below, my AuthenticationService looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private isLoggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    console.log('logging in user');
    console.log(username);
    return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
          const user = response.json();
          if (user && user.token) {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            // set the isLoggedIn boolean value to true, so that we can display this in the header
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
          }

          return user;
      });
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    // set the isLoggedIn boolean value to false, so that we can display this in the header
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

And my HeaderComponent looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  isLoggedIn() {
    const isLogged = this.authService.loggedIn();
    console.log('isLogged = ' + isLogged);
    return isLogged;
  }
}
```

My header.html is like this:

```
<!-- Show this for logged out users -->
<ul *ngIf='isLoggedIn() == false'
    class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"
      routerLink="/register"
      routerLinkActive="active">
      Sign Up
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Show this for logged in users -->
<ul *ngIf='isLoggedIn() == true'
    class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"
      [routerLink]="['/profile', currentUser.id]"
      routerLinkActive="active">
      {{ currentUser.firstname }}
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"
       [routerLink]="['/login']">
       Logout
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Is what I'm doing correct?

Comment: Have a look here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to check in authService if the user is logged in and manage the DOM with *ngIf.

**Typescript**

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService,....){}

...
get loggedIn(){
    return this.authService.loggedIn();
}
```

**HTML**

```
....

<!-- Show this for logged in user -->
    <ul *ngIf='isLogged' class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"
          [routerLink]="['/profile', currentUser.firstName]"
          routerLinkActive="active">
          {{ currentUser.email }}
        </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

**AuthService:**

```
....
  loggedIn() {
    //check here if the user is logged by your usual way
    // and return true if logged or false, if not
    //something like
     return this.localStorageService.getData('user') && tokenNotExpired('id_token');

  }
```

You can also add a method in authService to get you the user's name, username, etc..

```
getProfile() {
    //access to API to get info
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at my edited post! I have an AuthenticationService that actually does the login!

Comment: It's loggedIn, a method that will check if the user is actually is logged. It will just return a boolean. Based on that value you can show/hide the part in the view. See the small update

Comment: Have a look at my edited post! I guess I'm missing something very tiny somewhere! Could you please validate?

Comment: I guess I needed to check for true or false! I have corrected it! Could you let me know if this is Okay?

Comment: The issue you can have with isLoggedIn inside login  in authService, that once the session is over, its value is gone. Will need to check in a separate method for each session. I am looking close for the rest :)

Comment: I could not follow! Could you please provide a snippet of what you mean?

Comment: Look in my post at authService part.  The method   loggedIn() is checking on demande if the user is logged.